# Heroku use index.php for all not existent file paths

Tags: php, heroku

I'm trying to set up a single page application with php. index.php routes all of the calls and updates the url using javascript. The routing works fine and dandy on my local machine, but Heroku throws a 404 error when trying to go to /home or /about.

### index.php

```
<?php

$request_uri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);

// Route it up!
switch ($request_uri[0]) {
    // Home page
    case '/':
        echo "<script>history.pushState(null, null, \"$request_uri[0]\" + \"home\")</script>";
    case '/home':
    // About page
    case '/about':
        require 'views/templates/template.php';
        break;
}
?>
```

All I want is to customize Heroku's routing. For example: "/home" and "/about" would route back to index.php. Php's built-in server handles the routing like I want it, by taking every not found file back to index.php.

Here is the link to my site: https://shen-an-calhar.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting an answer for anyone else with this same issue. I realized that after running my code on a local apache server, I was getting the same answers.
I did a little searching online and I found a solution for running on apache:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This code needs to reside in the .htaccess file in the root directory for the routing to work. I don't understand every part of the code, but it works.